# Morphia Generics - Not Possible?

Tags: java, generics, mongodb, mapping, morphia

I'm trying to save a List of Generics(M) through Mongo/Morphia. I get this error when I tried to save:

com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Generic Typed Class not supported:   = class java.lang.Object

Does this mean that Morphia doesn't support Generics at all? Is there an alternative that would work? Using generics saves me 16 classes. There has to be an easier way that is allowed.

Surprisingly I haven't been able to find anything useful on this error.

Comment: If you look at the introduction page here: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/ you see it clearly supports generics. Do you work correctly with the EntityManager?

Comment: Where are you seeing it says it uses Generic Classes?

Comment: Erm, on the displayed source code? BTW: why don't you post a bit of your source code so we see the problem you have more clearly?

Comment: Nevermind. I went a different route and I'm just going to use a @NotSaved annotation on those variables.

Answer (score 1):

The error says everything:

> com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Generic Typed Class
>   not supported: = class java.lang.Object

Morphia does not support save generics in the DB, so, you can try to make a simple interface and then make all classes you want to save implement it, or something like that.

hope it helps;